# My quicksort desk test doesn't seem to be correct

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm currently practicing quicksort and it worked fine till now. But I could find an example where I fail (because it seems to be a Special case and I didn't read about it yet, that's why I do it wrong.. cannot solve it). The Problem is I think because I choose the smallest element as pivotelement:

```
9 1 4 2 7 *0*  (star mark means pivotelement)
```

Now I set `i,j` where `i` will go through Array (move to right) till it finds an element which is greater than the pivotelement. And `j` will go through Array (move left) till it finds an element that is lower than the pivotelement. Found, we Switch the elements where `i` and `j` Show at. We do this till `i` and `j` crossed (aka "`j` is before `i`"). In this case we Switch the element `i` Shows to and index `i` with pivotelement... I don't want describe the entire algorithm now or it will be Long question..

```
9 1 4 2 7 *0*
i       j        but now we cannot find a j that is lower than Pivotelement. What we do?
                 I would continue by switching i with pivotelement:

*0* 1 4 2 7 9
          j i    But now is the Problem that i and j are in other positions
                 (j is before i). I have no idea.. Please clarify and help..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is fine, you have successfully pivoted.

The pivot is in the correct position and both sides of the pivot satisfy the condition that all elements to the left are less and all elements to the right are greater. The i index gets to a bad position on the last move of the pivot, but you dont care that you have broken that because you are finished with it anyway.  Now you recurse and quick sort the left and right sides of the pivot -- except there is no left side so in this corner case you only recurse to the right.

Answer (score 0):

QuickSort works on the concept of partitioning. In every iteration it picks up a `pivot` element and tries to place it in the position where it would finally be placed.

In the beginning `i` pointer is always kept at index -1(which obviously isn't possible so we just assign i the value -1 and only reference an array element after we have incremented it).

So in your scenario after the first iteration you get,

`0 1 4 2 7 9`

which is the correct position for the chosen pivot element.

**Explanation :** Since `i` is initially at -1, you decrement `j` pointer till you get an element which is less than your current pivot element(0). This brings `j` all the way to index 0(you need to add those conditions to your code to make sure no illegal memory space is accessed).

Finally `i+1`(where `i` is still -1) is replaced with the pivot element, so effectively 9 is replaced with 0 and viola!

Refer to [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/) link for a more comprehensive explanation.